# How to use Graphite's identity() function with Grafana?

Tags: documentation, grafana, graphite

I'm trying to set up a time function with Graphite and Grafana, and I found the `identity()` function in Graphite's [documentation](https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.identity).
But I couldn't enter the function into Grafana, how do I get it work?